# Generating a Board in python for a table game

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to generate a board like this in python.

This is the desired outcome:

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2
0           * * *          
1           * D *          
2           * D *          
3           * D *          
4           * D *          
5 * * * * * * D * * * * * *
6 * D D D D D D D D D D D *
7 * * * * * * D * * * * * *
8           * D *          
9           * D *          
0           * D *          
1           * D *          
2           * * *
```

So far I got this done :

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
0 * * * * * * * * *
1 * * * * * * * * *
2 * * * * * * * * *
3 * * * * * * * * *
4 * * * * * * * * *
5 * * * * * * * * *
6 * * * * * * * * *
7 * * * * * * * * *
8 * * * * * * * * *
```

Here is my code so far:

```
def makeboard(x):
  board = []
  for r in range(x+1):
     brow = []
     for c in range(x+1):
        if r == c == 0:
             brow.append(' ')
        elif r == 0:
            brow.append(str(c-1))
        elif c == 0:
            brow.append(str(r-1))
        else:
             brow.append('*')
      board.append(brow)
  return board

b =makeboard(9)

for x in b:
print(‘ ‘.join(x))
```

My first problem is, that if I want to make a board like 12x12 the numbers in the first row and on the side over 9 push my board off symmetry. So I would like to make them reset over 9 so they start again from 0. I need help in this.
My second problem is I can’t make my board like I need to generate. Hoping for some tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely enough I got a lot of errors trying to compile your code: indent errors, and somehow your code is able to run using `` `..` `` characters instead of the usual `".."` and `'..'`. I adjusted my code so it runs on my system; you may have to change it back.

That said: you were on the right track but gave up too soon. All it needs inside the double loop is more checks for what character to insert at what position:

```
def makeboard(x):
    board = []
    for r in range(x+1):
        brow = []
        for c in range(x+1):
            if r == c == 0:
                brow.append(' ')  # top left corner
            elif r == 0:
                brow.append(str(c-1)[-1]) # top number row, last digit only
            elif c == 0:
                brow.append(str(r-1)[-1]) # left number column, last digit only
            elif (x>>1) <= r <= (x>>1)+2 or (x>>1) <= c <= (x>>1)+2: # center 3 rows and columns (offset by +1 because the first number column throws the count off)
                if r == 1 or c == 1 or r == x or c == x: # the first and last character in each column and row is always '*'
                    brow.append('*')
                else:
                    if r == (x>>1)+1 or c == (x>>1)+1: # the center column and row
                        brow.append('D')
                    else:
                        brow.append('*') # everything except the center
            else:
                brow.append(' ')
        board.append(brow)
    return board

b =makeboard(13)

for x in b:
    print(' '.join(x))
```

The code adds a `'*'` twice because it just happened to be easier to do it this way. Those two separate tests can be joined into a single long line but that makes the process harder to read, so I left it at this.

Comment: Thank you for the edits. it works flawlesly, but i made some changes, i didnt use the >> operator.

Answer (score 0):

For making the numbers go back to `0` after they go past `9`, you can use the modulo operator for integers (`%`):

```
>>> for x in range(15):
...     print(x, x % 10)
... 
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
7 7
8 8
9 9
10 0
11 1
12 2
13 3
14 4
```

You could also use the `math.floor` and `math.ceil` functions to help find the midpoint, the row/column above, and the row/column below the center line.